# Duplicate entry when creating posts with slugs in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, slug

When I create first post it creates successfully, but when I create another post I get this error and my slugs won't work.

This is the error:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'posts_slug_unique' (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Gacho's Second Post, Body For Gacho's Second Post, 2018-08-10 15:19:30, 2018-08-10 15:19:30))

Here is my code.

```
 class AddSlugToPosts extends Migration
 {

 public function up()
 {
    Schema::table('posts', function ($table) {
        $table->string('slug')->unique()->after('body')->default();
    });
 }

 public function down()
 {
    Schema::table('posts', function ($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('slug');
    });
 }
 }



 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
        'slug'  => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug'
    ];
 }


 public function store(PostRequest $request)
 {
    $post = Post::create($request->all());
    Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully saved!');
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
 }
```

Comment: `dd($request->all())`, what is the slug value there? Isn't it already in a table?

Comment: you have a unique key constaint on the table, which is why it's throwing the error, make sure your slug value isnt repeated

Comment: @u_mulder I have value in the table for the first post and it it 1, and now when I try and create second post I get this error. It's like it is duplicating that value but I can't find solution

Comment: @pseudoanime Yeah I know that but when I'm creating another post I put different value and it is still the same mistake. It is duplicating value of slug of the first post.

Comment: @u_mulder are you not posting slug explicitly at all? try dd($request->all()); in your controller and if it shows an existing slug value, then you know the problem

Comment: @pseudoanime I'm __not__ an OP.

Comment: @pseudoanime I tried dd($request->all()); and it shows new values that I put, but when I remove dd and try again to enter I get the same mistake.

Comment: Add slug in fillable and remove default() from migration. Technically, unique values should not  contain default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should Remove Default() from migration first.**

Hopefully you have set default value to 1 which is is being saved second time.

**Possible Mistakes**

1-You did not add slug in **fillable** array in your Model like this.

```
protected $fillable = ['slug','title','body'];
```

2-You are calling slug with wrong name or you are not sending slug in request at all. If you are not sending from your form then create it in controller.

3- Your slug field name is not same as column name in database.